# Strange Lines Appearing In Object View Wireframe Mode

Tags: modeling, wireframe, object-mode

I'm new to Blender, having learnt about it from watching YouTube videos. I have created a model of a shoulder pad for use with a scale model, with a view to 3D printing it. The model itself looks fine in Solid Object view, and also looks fine in Edit view. However, when I look at it in Wireframe Object view, I see a lot of strange lines that shouldn't be there. Can anyone help explain why these lines are showing?

I have tried deleting all the edges and faces where these lines show, and then reconnecting the vertexes manually to rebuild the quad-faces, but the strange lines still show in Wireframe Object mode even after doing this. I have also deleted any duplicate vertexes using the remove doubles button after selecting all the vertexes in Edit mode.

Here is an image of the shoulder pad in Solid Object view:

[image: Solid Object View]

Here is it in Edit view:

[image: Edit View]

And here is what it looks like in Wireframe Object view:

[image: Wireframe Object View]

Any assistance you can provide to help me understand why this is happening, and how to improve my modelling to stop it happening in the future, would be most appreciated! Thanks!

Here is a link to my .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Go to the Tool Shelf (*T*) Tools-->Edit-->Shading and press the *Smooth* button. Does it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Blender to draw all edges in the Object Display Panel:

[image]

I believe that Blender does this essentially as a way to conserve processing power as well as to keep wireframe scenes uncluttered for easier navigation.